# Sql remote connection timeout

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

When i try to connect my remote sql server through server management studio it's ok . But , When i connect with them through program connection string it shows "Timeout Expires"

```
connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass"
```

And also when i try to connect using IP . It shows "Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection."

```
connectionString="Data Source=192.168.2.6,1433;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass"
```

But I can see them through SSMS . And Managing . Anyone met the issue before ...

Comment: I found the solutions ... Add Exceptions to firewall didn't worked for me , maybe i missed something . So, i just turned off the firewall . and its now ok ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have `Shared Memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes enabled` in the SQL Server Configuration Manager ?

Then create a user login pure for that Database, and assign that user to you connection string
also allow that user to `connect, create, select, update, delete` on that database

also try by using `Data Source=(local)`, or `127.0.0.1` as yr server name

Comment: Yeah i checked with the values all are enabled ... @John Blade

Comment: I try all set ... I can add table , edit table everything through SSMS . But not able to from my application ...

Answer (score 0):

If your database is not on local machine, check on the SQL Server  machine using **SQL Server Configuration Manager** if the **Shared Memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes enabled** and

**TCP port is 1433**

Comment: After setting the TCP/IPs TCP Port No to 1433 . The Instance is failed to start

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps after you have made the necessary changes in your SQL Configuration Manager as mentioned in many other posts.

- Ping the server from your cmd using the server name.
- If that does not work, try pinging using the IP.
- If you are not able to ping using DNS but are able to ping using IP, go to your hosts file and add an entry for the DNS in the hosts file and try pinging using the DNS now. It should work. This happens because the host is not resolved by your computer when you are on a network.
- Now try this command at the cmd - sqlcmd -S servername\ -U  -P . The username and password are the ones used for sql server authentication. If you are using windows authentication you don't need the username and password options.
- If you have all your settings right and your hosts being reachable, then you should be able to connect to the database using the above command and you have correctly configured your computer to remotely connect to the database.